# Javascript - regex to match universal selector(*) in a multi-line style tag

Tags: css, regex

I have encountered following piece of html code with universal selector in the style tag.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* {
font-family:Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>...</body>
</html>
```

I am looking for an efficient regex to match the universal selector.
I have used `/<style>↵\* {.*?<\/style>/g` but with no success. The problem is it's a multi-line string and it seems to not work with multi-line strings.

Comment: Try `\n` instead of `↵`.

Comment: Also explain why you want to do that.

Comment: Right way to parse HTML is HTML parser not regex. In very limited scope regex can be helpful but it's bad for maintainability , since HTML might grow more complex than that over time

Comment: For multiline try this `/<style>↵\* {.*?<\/style>/gm; `

Comment: @Znaneswar Even with the m flag, `.*` doesn't find line ends. `\n` is the way to go.

Comment: @MrLister It worked after replacing `↵` with `\n`. Thanks.

Comment: @Tomalak In my application I am receiving html from external sources. This html needs to be rendered in a div. The universal selector is messing up the styling of the whole app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better regex:

```
/([*]\s*{[^}]*})/gm
```

It matches the universal selector, the brackets and everything between. It works even if there are other rules between the script tags.

- `[*]` a litteral star
- `\s*` any whitespace
- `{[^}]*}` an opening bracket, anything but a closing bracket, a closing bracket

Comment: This is perfect for my use case. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

You may also try this regex

`/<style((.|\n|\r)*?)<\/style>/g`

tested http://www.gethifi.com/tools/regex

Comment: if this answer helpful to you please mark it as answer so that it will be helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

Right way to parse HTML is HTML parser ( like `DOMParser()` ) not regex. In very limited scope regex can be helpful but it's bad for maintainability , since HTML might grow more complex than that over time and is not a simple language that can be regex parsed.

That being said, in this case, if format is exactly as you stared this will do the trick of matching:

```
/<style>\n\*\s{\n(\s|.)*\n}\n<\/style>/gm
```

Let's break it down:

- `<style>` - obviously it needs to start with this literal
- `\n\*\s{\n` new line, character *, space, character { and new line
- `(\s|.)*` - capture group that captures either spaces or characters (0 or more of those) - basically the text you want
- `\n` - end of that capture group is new line
- `}\n` - character } and end of line
- `<\/style>` - obviously needs to end with this literal (mind, / has to be escaped)

I can build you more robust regex but for robust solution, as I already stated: **HTML PARSER is a way to go!**

Comment: My usecase is a bit different. Appreciate your help though !